# FlexBox collapse issue with md-toolbar

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I'm using the FlexBox module in in my Angular application to make a header. However, in the code written below, the header doesn't collapse into a column when the window size is decreased, neither does testing it on mobile show the collapsed view. I have played around with the directives quite a bit, the header goes smaller in size but never collapses into a column.

```
<md-toolbar fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout.md="column" fxLayoutAlign.md="center" fxLayoutAlign="center"  class="mat-elevation-z2"  color="primary">




    <button fxFlex md-button [routerLink]="['/', '']">
        {{ 'PUBLIC.MENU.HOME' | translate }}

    </button>

    <button fxFlex  md-button [routerLink]="['/', 'about']">
        {{ 'PUBLIC.MENU.ABOUT' | translate }}
    </button>
    <button fxFlex md-button [routerLink]="['/', 'about', 'us', 22]">
        {{ 'PUBLIC.MENU.ABOUT_US' | translate }}
    </button>
    <button fxFlex md-button [routerLink]="['/', 'about', 'banana']">
        {{ 'PUBLIC.MENU.ABOUT_BANANA' | translate }}
    </button>
    <button fxFlex md-button [routerLink]="['/', 'about', 'apple', 6, 'pear']">
        {{ 'PUBLIC.MENU.ABOUT_APPLE_PEAR' | translate }}
    </button>
    <button  fxFlex md-button [routerLink]="['/', 'secure-page']">
        {{ 'PUBLIC.MENU.SECURE' | translate }}
    </button>
</md-toolbar>
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We need an actual working code snippet reproducing the issue to be able to give a proper answer

Comment: Although I am very sure it's purely a CSS problem, and no external CSS files are being used except the flexbox directives, do you think a snippet on Plunker would help?